# What was the reason for "observing from outside shadow DOM should not see mutations in the shadow"

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to observe change in the input value of text input element of the custom-input element at document level in the following document:

```
<body>
  <custom-div>
  </custom-div>
</body>
```

where the Custom Div and Custom Input definitions are as follows:

```
<!-- custom-div -->
<template>
    <custom-input>
    </custom-input>
</template>

<!-- custom-input-->
<template>
  <input type="text">
  <span>Units</span>
</template>
```

As state [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#events-that-are-not-leaked-into-ancestor-trees) legacy "change" events are not leaked out of shadow root, and the Chromium's [test](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/6db8410315ac3ad9a6f5ddd46b3d699a29744e7c/LayoutTests/fast/dom/MutationObserver/shadow-dom.html) of Mutation Observer on shadow root states "observing from outside shadow DOM should not see mutations in the shadow."

So neither legacy change event with event bubbling, nor Mutation observers with subtree attribute change config would work here.
I am curious what was the reason for the second part of the test case?

Also, the only way to implement the above scenario is to set observers on each level of custom elements which set/update their attributes on change of values in their immediate child element?

Comment: I have also followed the trail of [this](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2013JulSep/0057.html) email, that lead to [this](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2013JulSep/0091.html) conclusion. As stated, they concluded with implementing a method for form elements to emit changes in their values, but I could not find this in Mutation Observers documentations.

Answer (score 1):

**Shadow DOM** realizes **encapsulation**.

It's the main reason/rationale of a Shadow DOM to isolate a Web Component's inner behavior (inside the *Shadow tree*) from the *document tree* outside.

So it seems a normal, expected behavior.

NB: If you need to catch tree changes in a simple manner, you can always use `<template>` in Custom Elements without Shadow DOM.

What do you want to achieve? In you example the need for a Shadow DOM is not obvious.

You can read:

- this [introduction on Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) if you want to learn more on Shadow DOM rationales,
- or a [focus on Event retargeting](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events) with Shadow DOM and Custom Elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Supersharp. I understand the encapsulation bit, but the irony is I can listen 'blur' event across shadow roots but not the 'change' event. That's why I was curious for the rationale of not allowing mutation observers to be heard across shadow root hierarchies.

For the application I guess with the encapsulation in place I am grappling with a larger problem of maintaining shared state across the application. I had read the articles you shared, but I have yet to find one which guides on maintaining a store and state across an application like say React does.

Comment: @samarthg There's a discussion on the subject between browser vendors here: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2015AprJun/att-0307/24-minutes.html#resolution13

Comment: Just noting that when v1 ships, if there's no native custom element implementation (like in Safari 10), custom element polyfills will fail for any custom elements inside shadow roots that aren't created with `document.createElement()` because polyfills use Mutation Observers to upgrade them.